# unable to decrypt 3DES with SessionKey

Tags: encryption, openssl, rfid, mifare, 3des

I'm developing a C project to read/write Desfire Contactless Cards.
Right now I achieved to authenticate and I'm able to read data from the card, but it's encrypted with 3DES.

I want to decrypt next message:

```
EB 54 DF DD 07 6D 7C 0F BD D6 D1 D1 90 C6 C7 80 92 F3 89 4D 6F 16 7C BF AA 3E 7C 48 A8 71 CF A2 BD D0 43 07 1D 65 B8 7F
```

My SessionKey (generated in Authentication step) is:

```
44 E6 30 21 4A 89 57 38 61 7A B8 7C A9 91 B2 C0
```

I know the IV={ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }

With this information, I can go [here](http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com) and choosing 3DES, CBC mode, I can decrypt the message and I have means to know that it's right.
It should be, decrypted:

```
10 1a 01 31 32 ae 03 de 39 b0 00 97 7f 65 e9 43 93 89 53 5c 9e 04 a9 3f 95 71 24 0f 0a 9b f7 ee d4 5b 1b c6 78 7a f4 36
```

Anyhow, I tried to implement the C code using OpenSSL des library and I find the next difficulty:

> I need 3 Keys of 8 bytes each, but I have 1 SessionKey of 16 bytes
>   long.

I tried to split SessionKey into Key1/Key2/Key1 without success.
I have read so much about it, the only clue i found is that I have to generate those 3 keys from my 16byte SessionKey (taking it as a password) but I feel it is too advanced for me.
If this is the only way, is there any tutorial about ossl key derivation (evp_bytestokey)? Is there any other way?

### Thanks

Edit:
So, right now I'm in a very weird spot. As noted by many of you, I had already taken first 8 bytes from Session Key as Key 3 (that's what I referred to with Key1/Key2/Key1). Anyway it seemed to not work, but slightly it did, which is what puzzles me.
I get:

```
Decrypted : 11 1B 00 30 33 AF 02 DF DE 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 14 C1 26 8F 03 20 20 41 00 30 39 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 75 B1
```

When

```
Expected : 10 1a 01 31 32 ae 03 de de 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 14 c1 26 8f 03 20 20 41 00 30 39 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 75 b1
```

So I get the expected result XORing first 8 bytes with 01. Does that make any sense?? As in OSSL docu it says: *Note that there is both a DES_cbc_encrypt() and a DES_ncbc_encrypt() in libcrypto. I recommend you only use the ncbc version (n stands for new). See the BUGS section of the OpenSSL DES manpage and the source code for these functions.*
But I have access only to older version... Could it be the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Size of session key

Since you refer to MIFARE DESFire and you are using a 16 byte session key, you probably use 2-key triple DES. This means that the 16 byte session key is actually two keys (8 bytes, or actually 56 bits, each with 8 unused "parity" bits).

In order to map this to 3DES with 3 keys, you simply need to append the first 8 bytes to the end of your session key, so that you get

```
                     +-------------------------+-------------------------+
16 byte session key: | 8 bytes                 | 8 bytes                 |
                     | 44 E6 30 21 4A 89 57 38 | 61 7A B8 7C A9 91 B2 C0 |
                     +-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
24 byte 3DES key:    | 8 bytes                 | 8 bytes                 | 8 bytes                 |
                     | 44 E6 30 21 4A 89 57 38 | 61 7A B8 7C A9 91 B2 C0 | 44 E6 30 21 4A 89 57 38 |
                     +-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

#### First block of decrypted plaintext

If the first 8 bytes of the decrypted plaintext differ from the expected value but the remaining bytes match, this is a clear indication that you are using an incorrect initialization vector for CBC mode.

Have a look at how CBC mode works:
[image]

So for the first block, the plaintext is calculated as

```
P0 = DecK(C0) XOR IV
```

For the remaining blocks, the plaintext is calculated as

```
Pn = DecK(Cn) XOR Cn-1
```

This means that only the decryption of the first block depends on the IV. The decryption of the remaining blocks depends on the preceding ciphertext instead.

Since you assumed the IV to be all zeros, the XOR operation does nothing. Hence, in your case, the plaintext of the first block is calculated as

```
P0 = DecK(C0) XOR {0} = DecK(C0) = '10 1A 01 31 32 AE 03 DE'
```

As this expected value deviates from the actual value that you get (`'11 1B 00 30 33 AF 02 DF'`). This most likely means that you used an incorrect IV for decryption:

```
P0  = DecK(C0)        = '10 1A 01 31 32 AE 03 DE'
P'0 = DecK(C0) XOR IV = '11 1B 00 30 33 AF 02 DF'
```

You can calculate the IV that you used by XORing the two values:

```
P'0 = P0 XOR IV
P'0 XOR P0 = IV

IV = '11 1B 00 30 33 AF 02 DF' XOR '10 1A 01 31 32 AE 03 DE'
   = '01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01'
```

As this IV differs in exactly the LSB of each byte being set to one, I wonder if you accidentally used the method `DES_set_odd_parity()` on the IV. This would explain why the LSB (i.e. the parity bit if the value was a DES key) was changed.

Comment: You're right I was using DES_set_odd_parity, and that was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the encryption is two-key 3DES, in that case repeat the first 8-bytes , bytes 0-7 as bytes 16-23: `44 E6 30 21 4A 89 57 38 61 7A B8 7C A9 91 B2 C0 44 E6 30 21 4A 89 57 38`.

Some 3DES implementations will do this automatically, some you must do it yourself.

If this does not work you will need to provide more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't need 3 keys of 32bits, but only one of 3*32bits, with the bytes in the good order
Best regards

Comment: "32bits" makes no sense, DES keys are 56-bits in 8-bytes (least significant bits are ignored), 3DES keys are 168-bits in 24-bytes and two-key 3DES keys are also 168-bits in 24-bytes with the first and last 8-bytes a duplicate of the first 8-bytes. Some two-key 3DES implementations will duplicate the first 8-bytes, some won't.